# In Jinja templates, how to combine {% trans %} with {% with %}

Tags: jinja2

I'm using Jinja templates (in Django) with the i18n Extension enabled. I can add translation blocks in templates just fine, like: `{% trans %}Hello{% endtrans %}`.

But there are some places where I use `{% with %}` to set the value of a string before including a template:

```
{% with title="Latest posts" %}
  {% include "_partials/blog_posts.jinja" %}
{% endwith %}
```

Given that inside a `{% trans %}{% endtrans %}` block "no statements are allowed, only text and simple variable tags" I can't work out how to set the string "Latest posts" up for translation as well as make it available to the included template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `gettext/ngettext` functions at the `with` block's variables:

```
{% with title=gettext("Latest posts") %}
  {% include "_partials/blog_posts.jinja" %}
{% endwith %}
```

The `_` shortcut for `gettext` is also working: `title=_("Latest posts")`.